# NULL pointer exception in mmc/host/sdhci driver code

Tags: linux-kernel

We developed an embedded system using ZYNQ7020 SoC with petalinux 2015-4 as OS, the kernel version is 4.0.0-xilinx. In the system, we use a 4G SanDisk SD card as extra storage. 
The system runs pretty stable most of time. But  occasionally, we got kernel panic issue due to “Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer” problem. With our debugging, the problem happens in the driver of MMC sdhci related. Here are the details.
The dumped original kernel error messages are:

```
Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000008
     pgd = dd6a4000
     [00000008] *pgd=1d67c831, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000
     Internal error: Oops - BUG: 17 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM
     Modules linked in: ipv6
     CPU: 0 PID: 915 Comm: bramservice Not tainted 4.0.0-xilinx          #47
     Hardware name: Xilinx Zynq Platform
     task: de517040 ti: dd41a000 task.ti: dd41a000
     PC is at sdhci_send_command+0x39c/0x9c8
     LR is at sdhci_send_command+0x4a0/0x9c8
     pc : [<c0387ae0>]    lr : [<c0387be4>]    psr:             800d0193
     sp : dd41beb8  ip : c001c5d4  fp : 00000001
     r10: 161c4000  r9 : 00000000  r8 : 00000000
     r7 : df041008  r6 : dd4ec890  r5 : dd4ec8f8  r4 : de5ff300
     r3 : 00000002  r2 : 00000003  r1 : 1e7f0600  r0 : 00000000
     Flags: Nzcv  IRQs off  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM           Segment    user
     Control: 18c5387d  Table: 1d6a404a  DAC: 00000015
     Process bramservice (pid: 915, stack limit = 0xdd41a210)
     Stack: (0xdd41beb8 to 0xdd41c000)
     bea0:                            00000001 00000000
     bec0: 00000001 00000400 de7f0600 1e7f0600 000005bd          00000000    00000000 de5ff300
     bee0: 00000001 00000000 00000001 00000000 c0baa444          00000000    b54acd3c c03887f4
     bf00: de5ff418 00000100 00000010 c00444b4 c0baa088          dd41a000    40000005 dd517640
     bf20: 00000000 00000093 00000000 de4fa700 00000000          00000000    b54acd3c c00505a4
     bf40: dd41a000 de4fa700 de4fa760 dd517640 00000093          de402400    00000000 c0050698
     bf60: de4fa700 c0bb83c4 de4fa760 c0052fac 00000093          00000000    c0ba4bd4 c004fda0
     bf80: 00000000 c0050064 f8f00100 c0baaf7c dd41bfb0          18c5387d    18c5387d c000860c
     bfa0: 000aa2a4 200d0010 ffffffff c0011ac4 00255e58          00000046    00000070 00255e58
     bfc0: 00000000 bec26a10 00000000 00000152 b648cf80          00000000    00000000 b54acd3c
     bfe0: b644cdd8 b54acd30 000a7bbc 000aa2a4 200d0010          ffffffff    ebfffffe ea0000c9
     [<c0387ae0>] (sdhci_send_command) from          [<c03887f4>]    (sdhci_irq+0x23c/0x794)
     [<c03887f4>] (sdhci_irq) from [<c00505a4>]             (handle_irq_event_percpu+0x28/0xe0)
     [<c00505a4>] (handle_irq_event_percpu) from             [<c0050698>] (handle_irq_event+0x3c/0x5c)
     [<c0050698>] (handle_irq_event) from          [<c0052fac>]    (handle_fasteoi_irq+0xa4/0x11c)
     [<c0052fac>] (handle_fasteoi_irq) from          [<c004fda0>]    (generic_handle_irq+0x20/0x30)
     [<c004fda0>] (generic_handle_irq) from          [<c0050064>]    (__handle_domain_irq+0x8c/0xb4)
     [<c0050064>] (__handle_domain_irq) from          [<c000860c>]    (gic_handle_irq+0x38/0x5c)
     [<c000860c>] (gic_handle_irq) from          [<c0011ac4>]    (__irq_usr+0x44/0x60)
     Exception stack(0xdd41bfb0 to 0xdd41bff8)
     bfa0:                   00255e58 00000046 00000070          00255e58
     bfc0: 00000000 bec26a10 00000000 00000152 b648cf80          00000000    00000000 b54acd3c
     bfe0: b644cdd8 b54acd30 000a7bbc 000aa2a4 200d0010          ffffffff
     Code: e58d1014 e5943178 e15b0003 aa000042 (e5993008)
     ---[ end trace ef6ec1f8e3ce8554 ]---
 
We reverse them via symbol table, and get the call stack as following:
     sdhci_adma_table_pre() drivers/mmc/host/sdhci.c:521
     sdhci_prepare_data() drivers/mmc/host/sdhci.c:829
     sdhci_send_command() drivers/mmc/host/sdhci.c:1049
     sdhci_finish_command() drivers/mmc/host/sdhci.c:1113
     sdhci_cmd_irq() drivers/mmc/host/sdhci.c:2428
     sdhci_irq() drivers/mmc/host/sdhci.c:2638
     handle_irq_event_percpu() kernel/irq/handle.c:143
     handle_irq_event() kernel/irq/handle.c:192
     handle_fasteoi_irq() kernel/irq/chip.c:536
     generic_handle_irq_desc() include/linux/irqdesc.h:129
     generic_handle_irq() kernel/irq/irqdesc.c:351
     __handle_domain_irq() kernel/irq/irqdesc.c:388
     handle_domain_irq() include/linux/irqdesc.h:147
     gic_handle_irq() drivers/irqchip/irq-gic.c:291
     __irq_usr() arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S:448
```

At line 521 of  sdhci_adma_table_pre(), sg_dma_len(sg) , but sg is a NULL pointer. 
We are using the default sdhci driver code of the kernel, and never made any changes on SD Controller and the driver part. So, we are confused how the problem could happen. Is it a problem caused by the SD card, or is there any known issues in that version of kernel/driver? Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow isn't a place when you may get debug support for 3d-party software. Submit the bugreport into appropriate bug-tracker.

Comment: Try latest kernel first. Problem disappeared? Solved!